# Xpages datatable cell colour based on cell value

Tags: xpages

I am trying to use an xpages datatable and set the cell colour of the cells in a column to be different based on the cell value.  What I am finding is that although the datatable is bound to a view and the collection is specified (to get the row value) this seems to not be available to the style section.

Here is an example:

```
<xp:dataTable id="dataTable8" rows="30" var="doc1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var View:NotesView = DivisionsView;
View.getAllEntriesByKey("ViewName")}]]></xp:this.value>
        <xp:column id="column1" style="width:75px;font-family:Tahoma">
        <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:doc1.getColumnValues()[1]
}]]></xp:this.value>
                <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:v=doc1.getColumnValues()[1];
if(v=="Yes"){"background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"}}]]></xp:this.style>
        </xp:text>
        <xp:this.facets>
            <xp:label value="Header" id="label1" xp:key="header">
            </xp:label>
        </xp:this.facets>
    </xp:column>
</xp:dataTable>
```

This just shows a doc1 not found error.  Does this mean the data bound to the datatable is not available to the style part of it?  Is there a way to do this?

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Edit: I cannot change the table cell style based on the view entries value, here is an exmaple that throws the doc1 not found error:

```
<xp:column id="column1">
    <xp:this.style><![CDATA[#{javascript:v=doc1.getColumnValues()[1];
if(v=="Yes"){"background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"}}]]></xp:this.style>
    <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1">
        <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:doc1.getColumnValues()[1]
}]]></xp:this.value>
    </xp:text>
    <xp:this.facets>
        <xp:label value="Header" id="label1" xp:key="header">
        </xp:label>
    </xp:this.facets>
</xp:column>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting this.style without using document values? I'm also thinking this may be happening on page load, before it loads the docs into the dataTable. Maybe try a clause that checks to see if doc1 exists, then passing in a default style if it doesn't.

Comment: Hi, I have tried using this.style without document values and this works.  I have also checked and doc1 exists - putting the values into the table using doc1.getcolumnvalues()[1] has no issues

Comment: Right, but there's things within the structure of a dataTable that check to see if the document exists before rendering. I'm thinking it's possible that your code is trying to compile on page load and there's no structure loaded. I could be wrong though.

Comment: I dont know how I could prove your theory Aaron.  If you set up a simple page do you get the same result?  Just to rule out me being an eeediot..

Comment: I haave created a simple XPage with your code above. Works fine w/o any problems.

Comment: Thanks for trying this out your end.  I seem to not be able to do the style on the table cell though (the above code is for the style of the value - my mistake).  Can you bind a style to the table cell based on the value from the view?
I have updated the main question with an excerpt of binding to a cell, does this work for you Sven?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *stylesheet* property is rendered not only for every value in the column, it is calulated for each row. This incudes the facet too.

This means if your column has a header and/or a footer, the *stylesheet* property is calculated for these *invisible* rows, but there is no row value (*doc1*).

If you change your code and add a try/catch you can see the result.

```
<xp:column id="column1">
   <xp:this.style>
      <![CDATA[#{javascript:
         try{
            v=doc.getColumnValues()[1];
            if(v=="Yes"){"background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"}
         }catch(e){
            return "background-color:rgb(255,0,255)";
         }}]]>
    </xp:this.style>
   ...
   ...
</xp:column>
```

Comment: great workaround and makes perfect sense.  I have now resorted to repeats on a table row, but have tested your way and it works just as well.  Do find datatables limiting though in use.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I would like you to check in your code.

First the code to bind data:

```
var View:NotesView = DivisionsView;
View.getAllEntriesByKey("ViewName")
```

What is `DivisionsView`? The actual code to bind would look something like this:

```
var View:NotesView = database.getView("ViewName");
View.getAllEntriesByKey("KeyName")
```

Second, in your code to add style you have used single `=` rather than `==` in `if` condition. So the code would be something like this:

```
v = doc1.getColumnValues()[1];
if (v=="Yes") {
    "background-color:rgb(255,0,0)"
}
```

Do these suggestions make it work?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated the DivisionsView is bound to the custom control.  This works fine with all bar the style issue.  Your suggestion is right, apologies that was a typo from trying to simplify the code to post on here.  Any other suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Please update your question to correct the typo so that others won't be confused. The code should work without any issues. The variable `doc1` should be available in `style` property. Is there any other place where you have used the `doc1` variable, that may be causing the issue.

Comment: have updated the original question.  I have looked at whether it is a unique variable and it is, I have also changed the variable name to test, same issue - reference doc1 not found

Answer (score 0):

I have given up on a datatable and got things to work using a repeat on a table row. That way I can control the style of the entire row and therefore each cell, it appears you cannot do this in a datatable as the options are all data column based. Thanks for your help though